# Not able to run react app after gridstack.js

Tags: reactjs, gridstack

I want to use gridstack.js in my react app to manipulate the grid functionality. But after importing gridstack, npm i react-gridstack, i am having the issues which i am not able to resolve. I did the install on new project as well but did not work. Any clues will be appreciated

```
npm start 

Issue:
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/gridstack/dist/gridstack.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'jquery-ui/data' in '/home/rbatra/Desktop/react-app/dynamicreact/node_modules/gridstack/dist'
```

Comment: It seems to me like it has JQuery as it's peer dependency. You'll probably have to install all the peer dependencies. Although I'm not a react expert by any means, I would recommend not using something that uses JQuery in a React project. Maybe there's an alternative out there you can use?

Comment: Actually, i need to resize the grid elements individually, so not sure if any alternate approach would be able to do that. Gridstack from documentation seems to do that, but i am not over with this error.